# how to deal with CapitalizationError during importing in simpro CSV in brightway2?

Tags: brightway

when I import a CSV file I get the following error:

```
CapitalizationError: Possible errors in upper/lower case letters for some parameters.
'_a3_spruce_yes'' not found; could be '_a3_spruce_yes'
'_a3_osb_thickness'' not found; could be '_a3_osb_thickness'
'_a3_primary_frame'' not found; could be '_a3_primary_frame'
'_a3_pp_density'' not found; could be '_a3_pp_density'......(continue)
```

and if I look into the csv file it looks like (I took only one input and project parameter as example, they are basically all so, with the A capitalized)

```
Project Input parameters
_A3_Spruce_yes;0;Undefined;0;0;0;No;(0/1) Choice of spruce 
....
Project Calculated parameters
_A3_Douglas_Yes;1-_A3_spruce_yes;Choice of Douglas
...(there also other calculated parameters but always with the same A capitalized)
```

Any idea on:
-why this prob
-how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the input file. The `CapitalizationError` is incorrect; rather, there are some references which refer to undefined variables in the input data, e.g. `_Wall_Weight` is defined in a long formula that includes the variables `_A3_OSB`, `_A3_Plywood`, and `_A3_PP`, but these variables are not themselves defined anywhere. The correct error in this case should be a `ParameterError`, and can only be solved in the input data (and in the exporting program that allows incomplete references to be exported in the first place).

Comment: damn I already changed the A into a but did not realized the S was capitalized
will create the issue now